# Can someone explain how the sql query works?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

The below SQL query gets all the first_names which have different last names.

```
select a.first_name
from names a
WHERE a.first_name in (
select b.first_name 
  from names b
  WHERE a.last_name<>b.last_name
)
```

I am not able to figure out how this exactly works. What I thought would happens is, for every row in the table the subquery will check if there exists a row with a different last name. But the checking happens among only identical values of first name. Can someone explain how this actually works.

Comment: This is a somewhat complicated way of finding rows in the names table where the first_name exists multiple times when the last_name values are different.

Comment: What, exactly, on the above don't you understand? Which bit, specifically, is confusing you? Though I feel that a `HAVING` would likely be an easier methid: `SELECT first_name FROM dbo.names GROUP BY first_name HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT last_name) > 1;`

Comment: My Confusion is how does the comparison happens, as in what happens first and what happens next?

Comment: What do you mean what happens first or next? Are you asking how the query engine makes the decision to find rows to return for this? Or are you asking about the logic?

Comment: As the sub-query refer the parent, there is no first : like said in my answer, that's an alternate syntax for an inner join.

Comment: @Larnu Can you please explain in the subquery why only the comparison between a.last_name and b.last_name happens only for the records having identical first_name.

Comment: I think it might be better to EDIT your post and describe what you really WANT, not just what the query is/does.  Are you looking for names that dont exist as a last name?  Such as Michael Tom, where Tom is highly probable of being someone else's first name and want to exclude?  Are you looking for records where the first name is the same as last name?

Comment: `a.first_name in (SELECT b.first_name` @ArunJose . `a.firstname` must match the value of `b.first_name`.

Comment: I am ok with results, All I am looking for is how  it gave the required results. Can Someone help me understand What would be the output of subquery?

Comment: This is a correlated subquery. There is tons and tons of documentation and examples of how this works. I am not sure what is difficult to understand about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, as I mentioned in the comments, I would recommend instead using a `HAVING` for this. It won't require 2 scans of the table, just one, it won't return duplicates for the same `first_name` and it's probably easier for you to understand:

```sql
SELECT first_name
FROM dbo.names
GROUP BY first_name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT last_name) > 1;
```

This *should* be fairly self explanative; it returns rows where there is more than 1 *distinct* value of `last_name` for each value of `first_name`.

---

For your query, let's just look at the `WHERE`:

```sql
WHERE a.first_name IN (SELECT b.first_name 
                       FROM names b
                       WHERE a.last_name<>b.last_name
```

Firstly, we "join" the 2 instances of `names` (aliased `a` ad `b`) where the value of `last_name` differs in the 2 instances. This will, likely, be an expensive operation; if you have a table will 1,000 rows, and it has 900 different values for `last_name` then you're going to end up with the join getting hundreds of matches for **each** row.

After that, it checks to see the value of `first_name` for the row in the instance of `names` aliased as `a` in the rowset from the join; it is does then there are 2 (or more) instances of same `first_name` with different `last_name` values.

Using an `IN` with a subquery is no different, in context, to using a literal list of values. `WHERE SomeColumn IN (1,2,3,4,5,7)` would be the same as `WHERE SomeColumn IN (SELECT I FROM SomeTable)` if the column `I` in the table `SomeTable` had the values `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, and `7`.

Answer (score 3):

You can read it as an inner join like this, or an EXISTS :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6dad0bb/5)

**Query 2**:

```
select a.first_name
from names a
inner join names b
on a.first_name = b.first_name 
  and a.last_name <> b.last_name
Group by a.first_name, a.last_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6dad0bb/5/1)**:

```
| first_name |
|------------|
|       john |
|       john |
|       john |
```

**Query 3**:

```
select a.first_name
from names a
where exists( 
  select 1 from names b
  WHERE a.first_name = b.first_name 
    and a.last_name <> b.last_name
  )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6dad0bb/5/2)**:

```
| first_name |
|------------|
|       john |
|       john |
|       john |
```

Comment: This would not, however, return the same results; likely it would result in more duplicates.

Comment: @Larnu oh yes, you're right. If we have more than two, you make more line. my bad

Comment: You could add group by a.first_name to this which should be the same thing as the original.

Comment: @SeanLange the original query make a line per first_name, so need to group by last name too ;) [answer updated]

Answer (score 0):

1. A syntax check comes first, followed by the creation of an expression tree (at which point you may additionally check for items and "line up") (i.e. fields do exist WITHIN the table). This is the initial stage; if there is a mistake, you just advise the submitter to get serious.
2. Then there's the analysis. A SQL query differs from a program in that it does not specify HOW to do a task; instead, it specifies WHAT THE RESULT IS. Logic based on sets. So you bring in a query analyzer (which ranges from awful to good depending on the product - Oracle has had crappy ones for a long time, DB2 has the most sensitive ones, including monitoring disc speed) to figure out how to best approach this result. This is a very intricate beast, and it may attempt dozens or hundreds of techniques before settling on the one he thinks is the quickest (cost based, basically some statistics).
3. Then that gets executed.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question the OP is asking, if I am honest. The OP doesn't appear to be asking "how does the data engine work?" (which would be a question for [dba.se]), but why does the query return the results they want, as they don't understand the query.